# Ubuntu 16.04 VMware 12.5 doesn't start (failed to compile)

Tags: vmware

My system kernel:

```
:~$ uname -a
Linux xxxxx-Lenovo-3000-G530 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Trying this:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
[sudo] senha para xxxxxxx: 
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:31,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:48:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:111:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:4:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:569:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:39,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:46,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:50:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:65:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:4:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:37:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1291:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:43:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:83:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:111:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:4:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:569:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:39,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:46,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:83:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:65:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:4:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:37:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1986:1: warning: the frame size of 1168 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIFGetUserPages’:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1169:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    retval = get_user_pages_remote((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, ppages, NULL);
                                   ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘struct task_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘long unsigned int’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1169:58: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    retval = get_user_pages_remote((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, ppages, NULL);
                                                          ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘struct mm_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned int’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1169:71: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    retval = get_user_pages_remote((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, ppages, NULL);
                                                                       ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct page **’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
In file included from ./include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4:0,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/driver-config.h:71,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:29:
./include/linux/stddef.h:7:14: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define NULL ((void *)0)
              ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1169:79: note: in expansion of macro ‘NULL’
    retval = get_user_pages_remote((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, ppages, NULL);
                                                                               ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1169:13: error: too few arguments to function ‘get_user_pages_remote’
    retval = get_user_pages_remote((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, ppages, NULL);
             ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: declared here
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1
make[2]: ** Esperando que outros processos terminem.
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmmon.ko' failed
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/netif.o
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c: In function ‘UserifLockPage’:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:120:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    retval = get_user_pages_remote(addr, 1, FOLL_WRITE, &page, NULL);
                                   ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘struct task_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘VA {aka long unsigned int}’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:120:41: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    retval = get_user_pages_remote(addr, 1, FOLL_WRITE, &page, NULL);
                                         ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘struct mm_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:120:56: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    retval = get_user_pages_remote(addr, 1, FOLL_WRITE, &page, NULL);
                                                        ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct page **’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
In file included from ./include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4:0,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/driver-config.h:71,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:19:
./include/linux/stddef.h:7:14: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define NULL ((void *)0)
              ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:120:63: note: in expansion of macro ‘NULL’
    retval = get_user_pages_remote(addr, 1, FOLL_WRITE, &page, NULL);
                                                               ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:120:13: error: too few arguments to function ‘get_user_pages_remote’
    retval = get_user_pages_remote(addr, 1, FOLL_WRITE, &page, NULL);
             ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1339:6: note: declared here
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
make[2]: ** Esperando que outros processos terminem.
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:36:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2260:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
 ^
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:36:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2261:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0
 ^
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-7G9QrA/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules. See log for details.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

As stated on Linux Mint [forum](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3496#comment-139754):

> Kernel 4.13 series is too new for VMware Workstation Player 12, there’s a newer version VMware Workstation Player 14, but noticed a bug, created VM’s do not appear in the main window (VM can still be launched by double clicking their .vmx file in the corresponding folder)
>
> – Latest version 9th Jan. 2018
> VMware-Player-14.1.1-7528167.x86_64.bundle

I installed it now and it works.

Edit:
If you encounter the error: "not enough physical memory available to start this VM"

try what stated [here](https://superuser.com/a/1261886):

```
cd /tmp
cp /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar .
tar xf vmmon.tar
rm vmmon.tar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/fadedd9c8a4dd23f74da2b448572df95666dfe12/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
mv -f hostif.c vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c 
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
rm -fr vmmon-only
sudo mv -f vmmon.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar 
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say, all this trouble starts with the update to VMWare 14.0. The installation was OK but in the first start and trying to load WinXP virtual machine, the CPU Pentium Dual Core  was not compatible and I uninstalled. After that I try to install the 12.5 and the errors starts.

Comment: Follow the steps and the result is the same.

Comment: OK. With this kernel: Linux xxxxx-Lenovo-3000-G530 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 . And the: VMware-Player-12.5.8-7098237.x86_64. Everything is working again.